# Error: At least one Resources member must be defined. when uploading template file CloudFormation to allow exterrnal DNS on EKS cluster

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

I'm getting the "Template format error: At least one Resources member must be defined." error when I try to upload a template file to cloudFormation to allow external DNS on my EKS cluster
the file I'm trying to upload is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Obviously I'm pretty new to this..can anybody give me a clue to where I am going wrong?
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1):

Your CloudFormation does not have `Resources` section which is required. Please check the proper [format of a template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-anatomy.html).

Comment: Thanks for that Marcin ...you were right.....in the end it needed to look like this. at the beginning

    `"Resources": {
        
        "ExternalDnsIamPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyDocument" : {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"

Answer (score 0):

The full code that fixed it was

```
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "The IAM Resources for External DNS",
    "Parameters": {
        "DeployRole": {
            "Description": "Decide whether deploy or not the IAM Role",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "no",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "yes",
                "no"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Conditions": {
        "CreateIamRole": { "Fn::Equals": [ { "Ref": "DeployRole" }, "yes"] }
    },
    "Resources": {
        
        "ExternalDnsIamPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyDocument" : {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [
                                "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "route53:ListHostedZones",
                                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [
                                "*"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ManagedPolicyName" : "ExternalDNSPolicy"
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```